# javascript: module calls a function in the file that requires the module

Tags: javascript, node-modules

My first time writing a js library. The library is intended to execute, at specific times, functions in the file that required the library. Kind of like Angular executes user implemented hooks such as `$onInit`, except that, in my case, user can define an arbitrary number of functions to be called by my library. How can I implement that?

One way I have in mind is to define a `registerFunction(name, function)` method, which maps function names to implementations. But can user just give me an array of names and I automatically register the corresponding functions for them?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a specific requirement that it do so, your module does not need to know the names of the functions it is provided. When your module invokes those functions, it will do so by acting on direct references to them rather than by using their names.

For example:

```js
// my-module.js
module.exports = function callMyFunctions( functionList ) {
    functionList.forEach( fn => fn() )
}
```

```js
// main application

const myFunc1 = () => console.log('Function 1 executing')
const myFunc2 = () => console.log('Function 2 executing')

const moduleThatInvokesMyFunctions = require('./my-module.js')

// instruct the module to invoke my 2 cool functions
moduleThatInvokesMyFunctions([ myFunc1, myFunc2 ])
//> Function 1 executing
//> Function 2 executing
```

See that the caller provides direct function references to the module, which the module then uses -- without caring or even *knowing* what those functions are called. (Yes, you can obtain their names by inspecting the function references, but why bother?)

If you want a more in-depth answer or explanation, it would help to know more about your situation. What environment does your library target: browsers? nodejs? Electron? react-native?

---

> The library is intended to execute, at specific times, functions in the file that required the library

The "at specific times" suggests to me something that is loosely event-based. So, depending on what platform you're targeting, you could actually use a real EventEmitter. In that case, you'd invent unique names for each of the times that a function should be invoked, and your module would then export a singleton emitter. Callers would then assign event handlers for each of the events they care about. For callers, that might look like this:

```js
const lifecycleManager = require('./your-module.js')

lifecycleManager.on( 'boot', myBootHandler )
lifecycleManager.on( 'config-available', myConfigHandler )
// etc.
```

---

A cruder way to handle this would be for callers to provide a dictionary of functions:

```js
const orchestrateJobs = require('./your-module.js')

orchestrateJobs({
    'boot': myBootHandler,
    'config-available': myConfigHandler
})
```

If you're not comfortable working with EventEmitters, this may be appealing. But going this route requires that you consider how to support other scenarios like callers wanting to remove a function, and late registration.

---

Quick sketch showing how to use `apply` with each function:

```js
// my-module.js
module.exports = function callMyFunctions( functionList ) {
    functionList.forEach( fn => fn.apply( thisValue, arrayOfArguments ) )
}
```

Note that this module still has no idea what names the caller has assigned to these functions. Within this scope, each routine bears the moniker "fn."

I get the sense you have some misconceptions about how execution works, and that's led you to believe that the parts of the program need to know the names of other parts of the program. But that's not how continuation-passing style works.

---

Since you're firing caller functions based on specific times, it's possible the event model might be a good fit. Here's a sketch of what that might look like:

```js
// caller

const AlarmClock = require('./your-module.js')

function doRoosterCall( exactTime ) {
    console.log('I am a rooster! Cock-a-doodle-doo!')
}

function soundCarHorn( exactTime ) {
    console.log('Honk! Honk!')
}

AlarmClock.on('sunrise', doRoosterCall)
AlarmClock.on('leave-for-work', soundCarHorn)
// etc
```

To accomplish that, you might do something like...

```js
// your-module.js

const EventEmitter = require('events')

const singletonClock = new EventEmitter()

function checkForEvents() {
    const currentTime = new Date()

    // check for sunrise, which we'll define as 6:00am +/- 10 seconds
    if(nowIs('6:00am', 10 * 1000)) {
        singletonClock.emit('sunrise', currentTime)
    }

    // check for "leave-for-work": 8:30am +/- 1 minute
    if(nowIs('8:30am', 60 * 1000)) {
        singletonClock.emit('leave-for-work', currentTime)
    }
}

setInterval( checkForEvents, 1000 )

module.exports = singletonClock
```

(`nowIs` is some handwaving for time-comparisons. When doing cron-like work, you should assume your heartbeat function will almost never be fired when the time value is an exact match, and so you'll need something to provide "close enough" comparisons. I didn't provide an impl because (1) it seems like a peripheral concern here, and (2) I'm sure Momentjs, date-fns, or some other package provides something great so you won't need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom! In my situation, "specific times" literally means specific timestamps. The module needs to know the function names because it needs to separately call `apply()` on each of them to set `this`. The module may call one function multiple times but with different `this`es. Users pass in the names when they instantiate my module object. You just showed that users can manually register functions, I guess the question now is that given the function names, can I automatically register them for users?

Comment: If you're using real modules instead of an old-school browserland "modules," then the names won't be usable. Symbols declared in one module are not visible to code in a separate module unless they are exported. And, using `apply` doesn't require you to know the names. I'll update my example to illustrate.

Comment: What my module does is that, given a long string embedded with action tags (method names) and a timestamp for each words in the paragraph, execute the action methods at exact time. Think of it as syncing animation with audio. So (1) I need method name to know when to `apply` what `this` to which function, and (2) I need execution time to be exact, that's why I will rely heavily on `setTimeout()`

Comment: I think you're going to need to post an example of one of those strings, explain how the referenced functions are defined, and possibly explain how the timing it supposed to work. But, I'll say this is starting to sound less like you are crazy, and more like there's a straightforward solution.